# Error : Cannot read property 'mountComponent' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

> Error : Cannot read property 'mountComponent' of undefined

Can't is use multiple component in one files

```
class Application extends React.Component {

  student = {
      name : 'Jacob',
      course: {name : 'ReactJs', duration: '3 hrs'},
      fee: 10000
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <p>Welcome</p>
      <Student student={this.student}/>
    </div>
  }
}

function Course(props) {
      return (
          <div className="course">
          <p> Course Name : {props.course.name}</p>
          <p> Course Duration : {props.course.duration}</p>
        </div>
           ); 
}

const Fee = (props) => {
    return (
      <div className="fee">
        <h4>Fees : {props.fee}</h4>
        </div>
    )
}

class Student extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
          <div className="student">
            <p> Name : {this.props.student.name} </p>
            <Course course={this.props.student.course} />
            <Fee fee={this.props.student.fee} />
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/Jack_8588/pen/dBXabb?editors=0010)

Trying to connect multiple components using class, Function and arrow method sometimes.

Does it require multiple files?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's `ReactDOM.render()` and not `React.render()`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Working Demo: [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-flower-fp9wc)